# How do I get Travis-CI to show build artifacts?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, artifact

I have added Travic-CI on travis-ci.org to my github project. 
The .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
language: csharp 
solution: MyProject.sln
```

So, when I go to 
https://travis-ci.org/username/MyProject/builds/somenumber
, then it shows the build as passing. 
I can also see the log-file, but I can nowhere see the the files generated (the .exe). 
Do I have to add anything to .travis.yml so it displays/publishes my .exe as artifact on my project's page on travis-ci.org ? 
Or do I have to flip a switch somewhere else ?
Or is Travis not thought to do this ?

**Note:** 
Show the executable on travis-ci.org (so I can link to it from github), not publishing it automagically as release to github, althought that would be fine, too.

Answer (score 9):

By default, the build artifacts are thrown away with the machine. What counts is the build and test result. If you want to retain some or all build artifacts, have a look at the `deploy` options: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/

Answer (score 2):

Travis now offers a built-in option to upload build artifacts to AWS: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/. To set it up you just have to enable the add-on and provide some configuration:

> For a minimal configuration, add the following to your `.travis.yml`:
>
> ```yaml
> addons:
>   artifacts: true
> ```
>
> and add the following environment variables in the repository
> settings:
>
> ```
> ARTIFACTS_KEY=(AWS access key id)
> ARTIFACTS_SECRET=(AWS secret access key)
> ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=(S3 bucket name)
> ```