# How to get files produced during a Travis-CI build?

Tags: travis-ci

I am using Travis-CI to test code in a repository. There are quite some files after the testing and I would like to have them at a persistent place. How can I do that under the context of Travis-CI?

As an artificial example, suppose my Travis-CI server runs a C program that stores a large number of integers in a specific file. The file can be found at the Travis-CI server after the build. But how can I get that file?  In my use case, this file is large and it would not make sense to read it from the console of Travis-CI; in other words, I would not consider using "cat ..." in .travis.yml.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Travis-CI to show build artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237865/how-do-i-get-travis-ci-to-show-build-artifacts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, here is what I got:

The most convenient way seems to deploy the generated files to GitHub pages. The process is explained here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/. In short:

- first, create a GitHub page from the repository under test. This can be done through the Github web of the repository. The outcome includes an additional remote branch  called gh-=pages generated.
- then, in `.travis.yml`, use the deploy section to specify the condition to do the deployment.